# Add IGNORE to an ALTER TABLE statement created by schema update

Tags: php, mysql, sql, cakephp

I just jumped in an existing project written in CakePHP. I created the schema file using

```
Console/cake schema generate
```

Now the user table was missing an `UNIQUE` keyword to the email field, so I need to add it. Sadly now some users registered their email more than once, so when I run

```
Console/cake schema update
```

the SQL statement

```
ALTER TABLE `users` 
ADD UNIQUE KEY email (`email`);
```

fails because there are duplicate emails.

Is there any way to make an automated *migration* or I must clean up the database before the update? thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should clean up the database before the update.

There is a usage of `ALTER TABLE` that will automatically delete rows where duplicate values are found, but you don't have much control over *which* row is kept.

```
ALTER IGNORE TABLE `users` ADD UNIQUE KEY email (`email`);
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/alter-table.html says:

> If `IGNORE` is specified, only one row is used of rows with duplicates on a unique key. The other conflicting rows are deleted. Incorrect values are truncated to the closest matching acceptable value.

This feature is deprecated in MySQL 5.6 and removed in MySQL 5.7.

Comment: Thanks, I was aware of the ignore option but it's not implemented in schema update. Is it possible to run some code before the update so that I can automate the cleanup? My purpose was manly this.

Comment: This is up to the CakePHP migrations tool. I don't use CakePHP so I can't give expert advice. If it were me, I'd do the cleanup manually, before running the migration.